# How to make a sparql query with unicode letters?

Tags: python, unicode, sparql, dbpedia

I am querying the french dbpedia (http://fr.dbpedia.org/) with SPARQL.

I am using Python and SPARQLWrapper if it makes any difference.

This 1st query is working Ok.

```
    PREFIX dbpp:<http://dbpedia.org/property/>
    PREFIX dbpo:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
    PREFIX dbpr:<http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
    SELECT ?wt ?summary ?source_url
    WHERE {
        ?wt rdfs:label "Concerto"@fr .
        OPTIONAL { ?wt dbpedia-owl:abstract ?summary . }
        OPTIONAL { ?wt foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?source_url . }
        filter (lang(?summary) = "fr" )
    }
```

This 2nd query doesn't work.

```
    PREFIX dbpp:<http://dbpedia.org/property/>
    PREFIX dbpo:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
    PREFIX dbpr:<http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
    SELECT ?wt ?summary ?source_url
    WHERE {
        ?wt rdfs:label "Opéra"@fr .
        OPTIONAL { ?wt dbpedia-owl:abstract ?summary . }
        OPTIONAL { ?wt foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?source_url . }
        filter (lang(?summary) = "fr" )
    }
```

The only difference is the value of the label. The page `http://fr.dbpedia.org/page/Opéra` exists in dbpedia and rdfs label is set as "Opéra".

I think that the query doesn't work because it contains the french letter `é`. I've tried several escaping (`Op%C3%A9re`, `Op\u0233ra`, `Op\xe9ra`) without any success.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `FILTER` is not made optional. So it doesn't match `<http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/Opéra>`, which has no `dbpedia-owl:abstract`.

```
PREFIX dbpp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbpo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT ?wt ?summary ?source_url
WHERE {
    ?wt rdfs:label "Opéra"@fr .
    OPTIONAL { ?wt dbpedia-owl:abstract ?summary .
    filter (lang(?summary) = "fr" ) 
    }
    OPTIONAL { ?wt foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?source_url . }
}
```

... works (and returns `<http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/Catégorie:Opéra>` as well).